Cannot add Google account on Ubuntu 24.04: Wayland Proxy bind error
When trying to add my Google account, the control center dialog stays grayed out after successfully signing in using Firefox (non-snap).
When calling gnome-control-center from a terminal ("WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 gnome-control-center") as described in https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/17d4i0e/anyone_having_issues_logging_into_their_google/?chainedPosts=t3_1cdq3g5, I get this error message:
Wayland Proxy [0x725bbbc52560] Error: StartProxyServer(): bind() error : No authorization
Any ideas?

One thing I did not try before posting the question: Using Chromium as standard browser for the process. This solved my problem!
After successfully signing into my Google account, Chromium asked if I want to allow an "xdg-open" process. I agreed and the control center dialog showed the options to allow/disallow e-mail, calendar, contacts and files from Google.
